# Jquery image hover how to create a nice hover fade effect with shadow and down movement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possiable to create a nice hover effect when mouse over a image. It should fade in and get some shadow and move a bit down.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, there's the `.animate()` function that can help you.  What code do you have so far that we can work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS:

```
.hoverImg {
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
}
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('.hoverImg').each(function()
{
    $(this).mouseover(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({'opacity': 1, 'margin-top': '5px', 'box-shadow': '2px 2px 2px #000'}, {duration: 500});
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({'opacity': 0.5, 'margin-top': '0px', 'box-shadow': '0px 0px 0px #000'}, {duration: 500});
    });
});
```

Caveat: `box-shadow` may not be animatable with jQuery alone. Check out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for a possible solution. Also, you'll (of course) want to add browser-specific prefixes for `box-shadow`, as it's not universally supported as a CSS standard property yet.

Comment: How to move the image a bit slow down like 5 px when hovering?

Comment: Oops! @Railsbeginner you're right. I forgot the closing parentheses after my selectors. I've edited my post to amend this. Good catch! Sorry about that...

Comment: by the way, here's a plugin that will animate the `box-shadow` property: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/